# Moving website from Windows to Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that I want to move from my computer onto a Raspberry Pi so I can set up an always-on home server.

I was trying to move it over by simply copying over the Wordpress site into `/var/www/html` and then copying the database files from `C://xampp/mysql/data/sitedatabase` to `/var/lib/mysql`.

This didn't work and I get the following error : "Error establishing a database connection"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to transfer the database. The database files are usually filesystem specific.

Comment: You should create the database and run the MySQL dump file to get all the tables and data .

Comment: You should change your new connection details

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: mysqldump worked! Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you moved your wordpress' site without any problems follow these steps:

1. Install a fresh copy of wordpress in /var/www/html
2. Edit your wp-config with your new MySQL details (username, pass etc.)
3. dump your database from your current and import it to your new Mysql (you can use phpmyadmin for easier export/import)
4. You can copy-paste your theme and plugins folders but I will recommend to manually re-install them and use importer for the theme's configuration and widget's configuration
5. Use wordpress' import/export to move all of your media files